# Improving performance of reading with bufio.NewScanner

Tags: go

A simple program to serve one purpose:

1. Read a script file line by line, create a string while ignoring any blank new lines or comments (including the shebang). Adding a ';' at the end of a line if needed. (I know, I know, backslashes and ampersands, etc)

My question is:

How to improve the performance of this small program? In a different [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64643397/12185309) I've read about utilizing `scanner.Bytes()` instead of `scanner.Text()`, but this doesn't seem feasible as a string is what I want.

Sample code with test file: https://play.golang.org/p/gzSTLkP3BoB

Here is the simple program:

```
func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("./script.sh")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    var a strings.Builder
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines := scanner.Text()

        switch {
        case lines == "" || lines[:1] == "#":
            continue
        case lines[len(lines)-1:] != ";":
            a.WriteString(lines + "; ")
        default:
            a.WriteString(lines + " ")
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(a.String())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is feasible to use scanner.Bytes(). Here's the code:

```
func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("./script.sh")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    var a strings.Builder
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines := scanner.Bytes()

        switch {
        case len(lines) == 0 || lines[0] == '#':
            continue
        case lines[len(lines)-1] != ';':
            a.Write(lines)
            a.WriteString("; ")
        default:
            a.Write(lines)
            a.WriteByte(' ')
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(a.String())
}
```

This program avoids the string allocation in scanner.Text().  The program may not be faster in practice if the program speed is limited by I/O.

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fk4Jp-hkZgD).

If your goal is to write the result to stdout, then write to a bufio.Writer instead of a strings.Builder.  This change replaces one or more allocations in strings.Builder with a single allocation in bufio.Writer.

```
func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("./script.sh")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    a := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
    defer a.Flush() // flush buffered data on return from main.

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines := scanner.Bytes()

        switch {
        case len(lines) == 0 || lines[0] == '#':
            continue
        case lines[len(lines)-1] != ';':
            a.Write(lines)
            a.WriteString("; ")
        default:
            a.Write(lines)
            a.WriteByte(' ')
        }
    }
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ColrG3CeDMp).

Bonus improvement: use `lines := bytes.TrimSpace(scanner.Bytes())` to handle whitespace before a `'#'` and after a `';'`

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to demonstrate these examples for me. As you said, it didn't speed up the program due to I/O limitations, but it's still great to remove string allocation when it's not needed.

Answer (score 3):

I used `strings.Builder` and `ioutil.ReadAll` to improve the performance. As you are dealing with small shell scripts I assumed that read the file all at once should not put pressure on memory (I used `ioutil.ReadAll`). I also allocated just once to make sufficient store for `strings.Builder` — reduced allocations.

- doFast: faster implementation
- doSlow: slower implementation (what you've originally done)

Now, let's look at the benchmark results:

```
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: test
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1038NG7 CPU @ 2.00GHz
BenchmarkDoFast-8         342602          3334 ns/op        1280 B/op          3 allocs/op
BenchmarkDoSlow-8         258896          4408 ns/op        4624 B/op          8 allocs/op
PASS
ok      test    2.477s
```

We can see that `doFast` is not only faster but only makes lesser allocations. Metrics measured are lower the better.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func open(filename string) (*os.File, error) {
    return os.Open(filename)
}

func main() {
    fd, err := open("test.sh")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer fd.Close()

    outputA, err := doFast(fd)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fd.Seek(0, 0)
    outputB, err := doSlow(fd)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(outputA)
    fmt.Println(outputB)
}

func doFast(fd *os.File) (string, error) {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(fd)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    var res strings.Builder
    res.Grow(len(b))

    bLines := bytes.Split(b, []byte("\n"))

    for i := range bLines {
        switch {
        case len(bLines[i]) == 0 || bLines[i][0] == '#':
        case bLines[i][len(bLines[i])-1] != ';':
            res.Write(bLines[i])
            res.WriteString("; ")
        default:
            res.Write(bLines[i])
            res.WriteByte(' ')
        }
    }

    return res.String(), nil
}

func doSlow(fd *os.File) (string, error) {
    var a strings.Builder
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(fd)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines := scanner.Text()

        switch {
        case lines == "" || lines[:1] == "#":
            continue
        case lines[len(lines)-1:] != ";":
            a.WriteString(lines + "; ")
        default:
            a.WriteString(lines + " ")
        }
    }

    return a.String(), nil
}
```

Note: I didn't use `bufio.NewScanner`; is it required?

Comment: Thanks a ton! i had the understanding that bufio was the preferred way to read files line by line, rather than ioutil. I'll test your dofast implementation and compare it with the code I'm working with. :)

Comment: @AdamWoolhether Yeah let us know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to improve performance by buffering the *output* as well.

```golang
func main() {
  output := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)

  // instead of Printf, use
  fmt.Fprintf(output, "%s\n", a)
}
```