# Are there any limits to golang csv readAll() function

Tags: csv, go

I am new to golang and using encoding/csv ReadAll() lib to read all records of CSV file. e.g
records := csv.NewReader(filename).ReadAll()

Just want to know are there any constraints that I should be aware of for e.g CSV file size etc..
How big CSV file can I read using ReadAll() without issues.

Comment: The only practical limit is the size of your RAM (it should obviously fit in your memory). Other theoretical limits are the size of `int`: number of columns and rows can't be more than what fits into an `int` (you shouldn't worry about this, your memory size will be the bottleneck).

Comment: (Just guessing) It should be limited by memory. Thinking in practice a CSV shouldn't be larger than a few Mbs, maybe we can think unlimited.

Comment: There are no [documented constraints](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv#Reader.ReadAll), therefor the constraints are only  what is imposed by your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The only limitation here is originating from the hardware's RAM.
- In case you come across such a problem you may resolve this (depending on the case) with stream processing.
- On stream processing, you read one element at a time before proceeding to the next one.
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52154800/10436848) is an example from another thread.